# DOM0/DOM1 javascript: If Element has border remove it, if not add it

Tags: javascript

I have a page with two images on it.  One has a border, one does not.

Need to create functionality so if a border is present, it is removed.  If it is not present, it is added.

Using DOM0/1 javascript only, no Jquery .toggleClass or what have you.  At a loss where to start...

Comment: Which part are you having problems with exactly? What do you have so far?

Comment: Look into: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

A really simple example...

html:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;">hello</div>
<div>and hi</div>
```

js:

```
toggleBorder = function(e)
{   
    if(e.target.style.border == "")
        e.target.style.border = "1px solid black";
    else
        e.target.style.border = "";
}

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

divs[0].onclick = toggleBorder;
divs[1].onclick = toggleBorder;
```